# Excel VBA Auto Filter Pivot Table

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have compiled VBA code to filter through each name in a pivot table and then call other subroutines to manipulate and format the table. This code has worked perfectly for me in the past but after updating the source table and making minor formatting changes to the pivot table it now fails me.

Here is the code:

```
Sub AutoFilterEachName()

Piv_Sht = ActiveSheet.Name
Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Select
For Each PivotItem In ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PageFields(1).PivotItems
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PageFields(1).CurrentPage = PivotItem.Value
Call PivotCopyFormatValues
Call DeleteRows2
Call DeleteRows2
Call AddComment
Call Move_Save_As

Sheets(Piv_Sht).Select

Next
End Sub
```

First: the line `ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PageFields(1).CurrentPage = PivotItem.Value` doesn't change the filter to the first value of the Name filter when the code is started.

Second: When the routine reaches `Next` it goes to `End Sub` with out going back up to the `For Each` line. I have tried adding `Next PivotItem` whit no results. So it runs through the code once and stops.

I am at a dead end so any help is appreciated.

Comment: IMPORTANT NOTE: Before setting a PageField through VBA, it is vitally important to run the .ClearAllFilters method on the PivotField first. If a PageField has already been selected, then the line of code for setting a PageField will do one of two things: If a PivotItem can be found with that name, it is set as the PageField as expected. However, if a PivotItem can't be found, then excel WILL RENAME THE CURRENT PIVOT ITEM TO THE SPECIFIED VALUE! (It does this because .Name is the default property.) Clearing filters first will instead force an error to be thrown if the pivot item does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the 7 month delayed response; if you still need help...I think this might help you achieve the result you are seeking:

```
Sub AutoFilterEachName()

    Dim pTbl As PivotTable
    Dim piv_sht As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Set piv_sht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set pTbl = piv_sht.PivotTables(1)

    piv_sht.Select

    For i = 1 To pTbl.PageFields(1).PivotItems.Count

       'set the PageField page equal to the name of the PivotItem at index i
       'if you need to cycle through multiple PageFields, consider a nested For loop or For Each loop
        pTbl.PageFields(1).CurrentPage = pTbl.PageFields(1).PivotItems(i).Name

        Call PivotCopyFormatValues
        Call DeleteRows2
        Call DeleteRows2
        Call AddComment
        Call Move_Save_As

        piv_sht.Select

    Next i

End Sub
```

One reason your `For Next` wasn't executing and going immediately to `End Sub` is because your `PageFields` were empty; if there are no `PageFields` to loop through, then your loop will exit immediately. One solution to this is to always make sure there is at least one `PageField`. You could achieve this by entering this code before your `For Loop`:

```
pTbl.PivotFields(1).Orientation = xlPageField
```

This will insert the first `PivotField` in your table as the `PageField`.